# Login Php - Two or More sessions

Tags: php, session, authentication, types

I have a login code from a template and I want to add two more sessions to the code so there is actually three sessions, one for admin, adult and junior. I would like the code to chose the session by the user type variable set in the php. So e.g. if user_type="junior" then the location is junior.php. The code itself:

```
<?php 
require("config.php"); 
$submitted_username = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $login_ok = false; 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        } 
        if($check_password === $row['password']){
            $login_ok = true;
        } 
    } 

   if($login_ok){ 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;  
        header("Location: secret.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to: secret.php"); 
    } 
    else{ 
        print("Login Failed."); 
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

I am really struggling with this and any help will be appreciated as I'm new to php.

Comment: Sessions are like Highlander - there can be only one. However, you can specify as many variables as you like within that session to define the 'role'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do I specify variables to define a role within a session?

Comment: You already are : `$_SESSION['user'] = $row;` for instance. I'm assuming that you have actually started the session properly and everything in that *config.php* file you're requiring at the start of the script.

Comment: Ok, its working properly when I login and it takes me to the 'secret.php', however how can I make my code that when the user is "junior" it takes me 'junior.php' and when the user is "adult", it takes me to 'adult.php'??

Comment: Essentially what you really want is an RBAC; roles defined in the database with specific permissions and users assigned to roles. At it's most basic level you could just have a 'role' table and a 'role_id' in the user table. Retrieve the role with the login and assign it to the session with something like `SESSION['role'] = $row['role_id'];` and then determine what to do based on that ... this is a greatly simplified example; there's a more in-depth overview on wikipedia for example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control